# Object in loop of php

Tags: php

I am using webclientprint php for my POS system. I want to print number of barcode which can be done this way

```
$cpj->printFileGroup = array(
     new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
     new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
     new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
);
```

It will send 3 print request to printer.

**My question is that, can we make a loop of follwoing code**

```
new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
```

**like this**

```
new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
```

Please help!

Comment: you can make a loop anytime you want... http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = array(
        new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
        new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
        new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),
        new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null),   
    );

$cpj->printFileGroup = implode( ',', $collection );
```

or

```
$string = '';
for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
{
    $string .= new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null).',';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you just want to print the same file multiple times:

```
$cpj = new ClientPrintJob();

$cpj->printFileGroup = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $cpj->printFileGroup[] = new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null);
}

$cpj->sendToClient();
```

or try to build your array like this:

```
$fileGroup = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $fileGroup[] = new PrintFile($png, $tempFileName, null);
}

$cpj = new ClientPrintJob();
$cpj->printFileGroup = $fileGroup;
$cpj->sendToClient();
```

Comment: Thanks for help, for look value is 4 but your code giving me one print only. Any idea?

Comment: @KhurramSohail eventually, you have to build you array similar and assign the array itself in the end. have a look at my second example.